# T-SQL query to count number of rows where a date is bound between dates defined in other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, window-functions

I have a set of data showing the deals of each company and the date when the deal happened.

I create a new column of the date 5 years before the deal happened (`deal_date_5y_back`).

| company_id | deal_id | deal_date | deal_date_5y_back |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 86 | 1 | 2006-02-27 | 2001-02-27 |
| 86 | 2 | 2012-04-01 | 2007-04-01 |
| 86 | 3 | 2015-03-23 | 2010-03-23 |
| 86 | 4 | 2018-09-19 | 2013-09-19 |

I want to create a new column that counts the number of deals between the `deal_date` and the `deal_date_5yb`, for each company and each `deal_date`.

Essentially I want to write something like in the `count over partition by` clause below, but I am not sure how to do it.

```
select 
    company_id
    , deal_date
    , count(distinct deal_id) over (partition by company_id, deal_date where deal_date between deal_date_5yb and dateadd(day, -1, deal_date) ) num_deals_5y_back
from 
    (select 
         company_id, deal_id, deal_date, 
         dateadd(year, -5, deal_date) deal_date_5y_back
     from 
         DEALS_TABLE
     where 
         deal_date is not null) T
group by 
    company_id, deal_date
```

The output I expect is:

| company_id | deal_id | deal_date | deal_date_5yb | num_deals_5yb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 86 | 1 | 2006-02-27 | 2001-02-27 | 0 |
| 86 | 2 | 2012-04-01 | 2007-04-01 | 0 |
| 86 | 3 | 2015-03-23 | 2010-03-23 | 1 |
| 86 | 4 | 2018-09-19 | 2013-09-19 | 0 |

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, a lateral join might be the simplest approach:

```
select d.*, d1.*
from deals_table d
cross apply (
    select count(*) num_deals_5y_back
    from deals_table d1
    where d1.company_id = d.company_id
      and d1.deal_date >= dateadd(year, -5, d.deal_date)
      and d1.deal_date <  d.deal_date
) d1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/eOXK3WKu)**

---

For what it's worth: in databases that support standard date arithmetics in the `range` clause of window functions, we could do this without a subquery:

```
select d.*,
    count(*) over(
        partition by company_id
        order by deal_date
        range between interval '5' year preceding and current row
    ) - 1 num_deals_5y_back
from deals_table d
```

This [works in Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/Kn-2AXvW), and [in Oracle as well](https://dbfiddle.uk/N8-Hz50q) - alas not in SQL Server, as [the documentation points out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#unbounded-following):

> `<unsigned value specification> FOLLOWING`
>
> Specified with  to indicate the number of rows or values to
> follow the current row. [..]. This specification is not allowed for
> RANGE.

Attempting to [force the use of such clause](https://dbfiddle.uk/oOuu_cSA) raises the following error message:

> RANGE is only supported with UNBOUNDED and CURRENT ROW window frame delimiters